# Как парсить картинки с сайта, которые подгружаются кнопкой, с помощью jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

Добрый день.

В общем, есть сайт, на нем выведены 8 картинок. С помощью кнопки "загрузить еще", список картинок дополняется еще восемью экземплярами. И так пока до конца не дойдет. У инстаграмма аналогичная схема. У меня получилось спарсить первые восемь картинок, теперь не знаю, как парсить остальные? Android + Jsoup.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как парсить в таких случаях? Я так понимаю, чтобы спарсить все картинки, нужно прожать кнопку "загрузить еще" нужное кол-во раз программно. Или нет?

Comment: остальные картинки загружаются динамически, в изначальном HTML их нет. Это значит, что при помощи JSOUP вы их загрузить не сможете. Вам нужно сначала выполнить такой же запрос, как сайт делает к серверу, догружая картинки

Comment: Тогда логично ли в приложение добавить кнопку как на сайте "загрузить еще"?

Comment: Обычно, постраничная загрузка происходит автоматически, когда показывается последний элемент списка (это если вы используете списки). Я бы не делал кнопку, а загружал автоматически